# Ler um ficheiro txt (Aplicação Ping)

Tags: c#, aplicação-desktop, ping

Tenho um ficheiro txt que cada linha contem o ip mais o nome do servidor:

Exemplo:
Ip;nomedoservidor (1º Linha)
Ip;nomedoservidor (2º Linha)
Ip;nomedoservidor (3º Linha)

O que eu pretendia era que o meu programa fosse ler esse ficheiro e executasse um ping a cada ip contido no txt, o problema é que para alem do ip o nome também está contigo nessa mesma linha.
O nome do servidor deverá ser usado apenas na ConsoleWriteLine para saber qual servidor está "Timeout" ou "Success"

o meu código neste momento é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o ficheiro txt está organizado na seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo um exemplo para testar os ips (com nomes do servidor) em cada linha do arquivo, conforme você especificou:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace ConsoleTestePing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero; //Começar a contar a partir do 0
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); //Periodo de tempo do intervalo (neste caso a cada 5 minutos)


            var ips = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\IPS.txt");


            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            {
                PingnosIps(ips);

            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void PingnosIps(string[] ips) //Método Ping
        {
            var servidores = ips.ToList().Select(o => new { Ip = o.Split(';')[0], NameServer = o.Split(';')[1] });

            foreach (var serv in servidores)
            {
                String ip = serv.Ip;
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = ping.Send(ip); //Faz ping a string ip (que contem o ip no exemplo)
                string status = reply.Status.ToString(); //Transforma o estado da resposta para string
                Console.WriteLine($"Servidor: {serv.NameServer} IP: {serv.Ip} Status: {status}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!